# What kind of saw would I use to cut a shape out of a panel?

Tags: wood

It's is a nice even cut trying to find out what kind of saw.

[image]

Comment: What type of material? A rotary tool with a spiral bit would be great for thin or soft material.

Comment: Is it just me or did the designer of that board have a hidden message?

Comment: A router is another option.  A lot depends on whether you have a template or not.

Comment: The gentle inside corners imply mass production cutting methods, i.e. with a die or a laser.

Answer (score 21):

You'd want a hand held jig saw
[image: jig saw]

Or a stationary band saw
[image: bench top band saw]

or a scroll saw
[image: scroll saw]

You could also do it with a hand held coping saw
[image: coping saw]

But it would be alot of work and difficult to get good square, smooth results with the coping saw.

It takes some practice & skill, and/or a good bit of sanding & filing to get those nice smooth cuts with either tool.  You'll also need a drill & bits to drill out the tighter corners - either of the tools, with the possible exception of the scroll saw, will have some trouble cutting some of those smaller radius inside corners without drilling it out first.

Comment: Nitpick, but a scroll saw should work a bit better than that band saw even though they are very similar..

Comment: You're probably right - I'll admit I don't have much experience with scroll saws.  Added to the answer

Comment: It doesn't help you much with the first one, but if I was trying to make multiples of something like this I would probablly use a router with an edge-following bit.

Comment: Yea, I agree.  But probably well above the level of expertise of the poster.

Comment: The jigsaw won't give a very smooth cut.

Comment: I'd definitely avoid the first tool suggested here - there's too much narrow arcs (ears, fingers). This tools has some turn radius, like a car. Unless you are proficient with it, it's pretty hard to keep on-track. Also cutting the concave holes above the hands can easily turn into nightmare. You can you leave some safety margin but you'd have to remove it later with other tool. If you can choose&afford a dedicated tool, the scroll saw is just the tool for that. Scroll saw is often used for works like https://i.pinimg.com/originals/78/c3/f8/78c3f88c5c9d66687b1b4f5281e01bd5.jpg

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are dealing w/ a thin material.  I think a Dremel tool would be able to easily cut thru it while providing the accuracy and maneuverability needed.

It is also fairly inexpensive as it is more suited for craft and lightweight DIY projects.

https://express.google.com/u/0/product/18390795439829211245_7899309295047230687_6136318